# angular2 and Typescript array - Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => void'

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I init an empty array?

```
test: any[];

//On change I want to add an item to an array
test(){ 
  this.test.push('a');
}
```

> error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => void'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't initialize your array, so `test` is `undefined`. To be able to use it, just initialize it this way:

```
test: any[] = [];
```

Comment: I have the same issue as IntelliJ warning, but it's probably just an IntellIJ bug. The TypeScript compiler does not complain about it.

Comment: I wanted to comment on Thierry's reply, but lack of reputation. You must use the same typescript version in your IDE as the version in angular config, to avoid seeing any syntax errors and code-completion suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**Try any of these solutions:**

```
const test = [];
test.push('a');
```

OR

```
const test = [];
const name = 'a';
test.push({ 'name' : name});
```

You can add it to your function like:

```
test(name: string){
    const test = [];
    test.push({ 'name' : name});
}
```